# Вызов метода расширения

Tags: c#

Могу ли я вызвать метод Click в методе ClickAt?

```
namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class MyCursorExtensions
    {
        public static void Click(this Cursor cs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Clicking at position");
        }

        public static void ClickAt(this Cursor cs, Point newPosition)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("New position is {0}", newPosition);
            //Предполагается, что здесь я вызову Click();
        }
```

Comment: Нет. Я запрещаю даже пытаться это делать!

Comment: @alexolut, да ну не пугайте Вы так человека! Вдруг и правда испугается, да не попробует! :)

Comment: Вообще, лучше сначала попробовать сделать это самому. А в случае неудачи уже вопросы задавать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конечно, вызывайте:

```
cs.Click();
```

В самом пиковом случае:

```
MyCursorExtensions.Click(cs);
```

То есть:

```
public static void ClickAt(this Cursor cs, Point newPosition)
{
  Console.WriteLine("New position is {0}", newPosition);

  cs.Click();
  // или
  MyCursorExtensions.Click(cs);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Я, конечно, не спец в С#. Но все же осмелюсь предположить, что можно :)). Когда будете вызывать метод, передайте ему ссылку на `Cursor`.

Comment: Правда? Что вы передадите первым аргументом, когда вызовите Click из ClickAt? :)

Comment: @J.John, ну, судя по всему, объект типа `Cursor` :).

Comment: @Igor, а это смотря как вызывать ;)

Comment: Товарищи, думаю нужно закрыть вопрос. Я не сразу догадался, что в данном классе, метод Click можно вызвать с ссылкой на объект. "Из вне" можно вызвать без аргумента, а внутри класса нельзя)

Comment: @J.John, я Вам сейчас как закрою! Низя, тут ответы есть! :) Я лучше ответ отредактирую.

Comment: @J.John, примите мой ответ или Егора.